# Centering with margin

Tags: html, css

I would to make my navbar on center. Tried this:

```
  #menu {
      position: relative;
      height: 44px;
      width: auto;
      padding-left:165px;
    }
```

But, this code does not works on large screen or zoom out. And I've tried

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Here is my full navbar codes

```
#menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 44px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
#menu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#4F93EF, #1162CB);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#4F93EF, #1162CB);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4F93EF, #1162CB);
  /*border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border: 15px 15px 0px 0px;*/
  width: 1020px;
  z-index: 500;
}
#menu:after,
#menu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#menu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#menu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family:Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#menu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #b6b6b6;
}
#menu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #b6b6b6;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0053a6;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0053a6;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#menu ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#menu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#menu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 190px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#menu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 190px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
  width: 150px; /*ukuran kotak*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #006ad4;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}
#menu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#menu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #0160bf;
  color: #b6b6b6;
}
#menu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#menu ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#menu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: '';
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #b6b6b6;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 30px;
}
#menu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
#menu ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #b6b6b6;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#menu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #b6b6b6;
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
}
#menu ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #b6b6b6;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#menu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-right-color: #b6b6b6;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #menu {
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu.align-center ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #menu.align-right > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #menu .submenuArrow,
  #menu #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #menu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #menu li,
  #menu > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu ul ul,
  #menu ul ul ul,
  #menu ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu ul ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu.align-right ul ul,
  #menu.align-right ul ul ul,
  #menu.align-right ul > li:hover > ul,
  #menu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  #menu ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #menu ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
  }
  #menu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #menu ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #b6b6b6;
  }
  #menu ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
  }
  #menu ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #menu ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #menu ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #menu > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #menu #menu-button > a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
  }
  #menu ul.open li,
  #menu > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #menu > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #menu ul ul::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #menu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #menu ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #menu ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

I've tried margin-left auto, margin-right auto and margin 0px auto
Still does not work, any solution guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to fix the width of the parent tag and set the style="margin:0px auto;"

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `margin-left` and `margin-right` is incorrect, it should be:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use left and right with auto

```
#menu {
      position: relative;
      height: 44px;
      width: auto;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      float:none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
#menu {
    position: relative; 
    height: 44px;
    width: 500px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0; 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: red;
    color: white; 
    display: block;
    }
```

PS: try the position as absolute or fixed also instead of relative.